# add count of zeros by group using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a very large data frame I need to filter by brands with more than 50 available rows and less than 10 zero values in column valuation.
I use dplyr

Reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(brand=c("Advert","Advert","Bass","Bass","Bass"),
                 date=c("2019-07-15","2019-08-15","2018-01-01","2018-02-15","2015-01-10"),
                 valuation=c(0,1,0,1,1))

# What I have reached so far...

 df %>% dplyr::add_count(brand) %>% group_by(brand) %>% add_count(valuation==0)


>  df %>% dplyr::add_count(brand) %>% group_by(brand) %>% add_count(valuation==0)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   brand [2]
  brand  date       valuation     n `valuation == 0`    nn
  <fct>  <fct>          <dbl> <int> <lgl>            <int>
1 Advert 2019-07-15         0     2 TRUE                 1
2 Advert 2019-08-15         1     2 FALSE                1
3 Bass   2018-01-01         0     3 TRUE                 1
4 Bass   2018-02-15         1     3 FALSE                2
5 Bass   2015-01-10         1     3 FALSE                2
```

I will use column "n" to filter Brands with more than 50 rows but notice that Expected result in column "nn" should be:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

In fact I need calculate proportion of zero values by brand group but I´m stuck on counting zeros by brand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add `n` and `nn` columns for filtering. You can directly `filter` like below:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(brand) %>% 
  filter(n()>50,sum(valuation==0)<10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `add_count` for the second criterion. You can directly use `sum`.

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::add_count(brand) %>% 
  group_by(brand) %>% 
  mutate(nn = sum(valuation == 0))
```